# Swift load from userDefaults into UItextfield.text

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, option-type

Im trying to retrieve a Int value from a userdefault and show it in a input field, but I keep getting the **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**, it must be a wrong placed ! or ? somewhere in this code. I have used hours now :-(

```
func LoadFromDefaultDistances(){
            if let v = defaults.objectForKey("DriverMin") as? NSInteger {
                inputDriverMin.text = String(defaults.objectForKey("DriverMin") as! NSInteger)
            }
        }
```

Comment: What exactly is defaults? How is it initialized. If v isn't nil, you are able to use it inside the if statement - no need to get the object from defaults again. If your error occurs inside the if statement check your Label. Seems to be nil at this point.

Comment: I accidentally wrote Label but of cause meant Textfield

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to save the value.

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject("Your in value", forKey: "myIntValue")
defaults.synchronize()
```

And use this code to get it back.

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if let theInt = defaults.stringForKey("myIntValue")
{
inputDriverMin.text = theInt
}
```

Comment: HorseT, i think 'defaults.synchronize()' is only needed in iOS 7 and earlier versions? Read some where that is might even slow your program down in iOS 8 and later.

Comment: "... is automatically invoked at periodic intervals..." Yes it will save your data but if your user quit the App it isn't guaranteed to be already synchronized.